# Getting error `The tenant admin disabled this bot` on MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft Teams Bot application called **Beep**. The app has been approved and is in the Teams App store.

Prior to the approval, we were sideloading the app and everything was working fine.

After the approval, we removed the sideloaded app and used the one from the store in **one Tenant it worked fine as normal.**

But in the other tenant it have this error shown below:

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        "content-length": "82",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "contextid": "tcid=0,server=msgapi-production-weu-azsc3-3-23,cv=ZAWkamQzUEOcNgegL4EseA.0",
        "pragma": "no-cache"
    },
    "errorMessage": "<BotDisabledByAdmin>The tenant admin disabled this bot",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "request": {}
}
```

The app is added under Third-party under `Global (Org-wide default)`.

The bot is enabled under the policy as well. Can you please guide me on what I am doing wrong or what steps should I need to follow?

Comment: Could you please refer this;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings#user-custom-app-policy ? Thanks!

Comment: So, the app we want is to install from the MS app source not to upload a custom app.

Comment: Could you please check if the bot ID is associated with 2 Teams apps, one in the global catalog (blocked by permission policy) and one in the tenant catalog (allowed by policy)? Sometimes this type of case brings out the error.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, what does `one in the tenant catalogue (allowed by policy)` means?

Comment: Log in to the Microsoft Teams admin center using this URL – https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps

In the left navigation of the Microsoft Teams admin center, go to Teams Apps > Manage apps. You must be a global admin or Teams Service admin to access the page.

Comment: Okay, yeah in both cases the bot is the same.

Comment: Navigate to Teams apps > Permission policies.

Ensure that 'Beep' is allowed for Third-party apps.
Ensure 'Beep' for Teams app is allowed for Custom apps

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, what do you mean by "Ensure 'Beep' for Teams app is allowed for Custom apps"?

Comment: 'Beep' is a third party app right? Is it allowed for Third-party apps? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNan9.png

Comment: Yes, it's a third-party app and is allowed under Third-party apps. But what do you mean by `Ensure 'Beep' for Teams app is allowed for Custom apps` in previous reply.

Comment: There is an ICM for this issue and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we have further update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 3. party apps are allowed in that tenant.

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies) for info

Comment: The app is added under Third-party under `Global (Org-wide default)`. Do I need to create a custom policy?

Comment: No, you don't need to create any custom policy.